# Permissions dilemma - Private key requires 600 for terminal SSH, more open for PHP

Tags: ssh, permissions, php

I have a private key file that will be used in the following two use-cases:

- `SSH -i /path/to/private/key` within terminal -- *Requires 600 permission set*
- A `file_get_contents()` statement within PHP -- *Requires more open permissions set*

The file currently has permissions set at `600` to allow usage within SSH via terminal. However because of this I get a permission denied when trying to read the file within PHP.

Please can anyone suggest a viable solution, whilst maintaining good security on the key file, to enable me to use the same key file for both the aforementioned use-cases?

---

Edit: For clarification, I'm using [PHPSecLib](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/) (as opposed to [PECL's SSH2 extension](http://pecl.php.net/package/ssh2)), to connect to an [Amazon EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) instance within PHP. The following is a code example:

```
$key = new Crypt_RSA();
$key->loadKey(file_get_contents('private_key.pem'));

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('amazon-ec2-ip');
$ssh->login('ubuntu', $key); // HERRO PRIVATE KEY
```

Comment: Why in lords name do you want to be able to `file_get_contents()` a **private** ssh key? This reeks of [tag:your-doing-it-wrong]... Seriously, what purpose do you have reading in the private key that you need it available for both?

Comment: I guess he wants to retrieve a file via ssh/scp and PHP has some way to specify a private key to use for this. Anyway, I agree that this is a horrible idea.

Comment: Updated with clarification. I'm creating an SSH connection within PHP, and this requires a private key. It's (*I assume*) a valid purpose, hence why I asked for a solution that maintains good security (if there is one) :)

Comment: Then create a new, separate private key... Don't re-use keys for multiple purposes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were to use [suPHP](http://www.suphp.org/), you could allow the script to run under the same user for the script that owns the key.

EDIT:

Based on your clarification (and others comments), it would likely be best to generate a new key specifically for the purpose of your script and give it the permissions of your web user. It is usually best to have a new key set up per user/script.

For more information on why this is best practice, have a look at [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/29440/ssh-reusing-public-keys-and-known-man-in-the-middle) and [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/10206/18424) link.

Answer (score 1):

If you care at all about the security of your private key, your only real option is to generate a different private key to use with the PHP script; this key would preferably be associated with a forced command on the server side, to limit the exposure resulting from the private key being compromised..

If you *don't* care at all about the security of your private key, you could recompile the SSH client from source so that it can be coerced into not caring about the permissions on your private key file.

And if you just don't care at all about security, period, then you could run the PHP script, and thus (presumably) the web server, under your own user account.